# linking mac framework to qt creator

Tags: c++, macos, qt, frameworks, qt-creator

I have a project that uses SystemConfiguration.Framework.

I've been using xcode, where adding the framework is quite easy, just add it to xcode project's framework. But now, I need my project to be cross platform, so I'm using QT Creator as a single IDE, for Windows and Mac. The problem is that I don't know how to tell QT Creator how to link to the systemConfiguration.framework. The header from the framework are correctly included, no problem there... just when is ending the compilation it complains that some symbols where not found, i.e, the symbols that are exported from the systemconfiguration.framework...

Does anyone knows or can help me to set up the Qt creator project to link agains that framework, please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume the project itself is using Qt i.e. it is using .pro files to configure things like include paths and library/framework paths? If so then you just need to update the relevant .pro file to add the framework.

See the [qmake docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-platform-notes.html#using-frameworks) for more detail. The gist of it is to add

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/path/to/framework/directory/
```

and

```
LIBS += -framework TheFramework
```

Comment: Thanks, Troubadour...

somehow I missed that section when looking at the qmake documentation... now with the LIBS flag, I have the project compiling.

Thanks

Comment: This was working for me until Qt 5.5.  Now it seems broken.  Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I haven't looked at this in a while now.  As I recall, I was forced to keep using older versions of Qt and XCode for a collection of reasons the newer versions of each introduced and I didn't have the time yet to resolve.  Please post a solution if you find one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works with Qt 5.6 here:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-platform-notes.html#creating-frameworks

> **Using Frameworks**
>
> qmake is able to automatically generate build rules for linking
>   against frameworks in the standard framework directory on macOS,
>   located at /Library/Frameworks/.
>
> Directories other than the standard framework directory need to be
>   specified to the build system, and this is achieved by appending
>   linker options to the LIBS variable, as shown in the following
>   example:
>
> `LIBS += -F/path/to/framework/directory/`
>
> The framework itself is linked in by appending the -framework options and the > name of the framework to the LIBS variable:
>
> `LIBS += -framework TheFramework`